# Application form not ending

Tags: c#, wpf

(learning c#)

I have a C# WPF application which when a certain form is launched does not allow the applications process to close. This occurs in both Debug and the released exe file. The process remains until killed via task manager.

It only occurs when this form is loaded, other forms that are loaded and unloaded allow the application to close normally.

Can anyone point our my error?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="FileDownloadService.FileEditorWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="FileEditorWindow" Height="347" Width="618" Name="FileEditor" Background="#FFF1E7E7" ResizeMode="NoResize" Icon="/FileDownloadService;component/Images/Folder%20Concept%20Icons%2034.ico">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,36,0,0" Name="txtDownloadName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135" />
        <Label Content="Download Name" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,36,0,0" Name="labRef" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105" />
        <Label Content="Download URL" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,70,0,0" Name="labURL" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105" />
        <TextBox Height="23" Margin="142,70,0,0" Name="txtURL" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="373" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,103,0,0" Name="txtSaveLoc" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="340" />
        <Label Content="Save Location" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,101,0,0" Name="labSaveLoc" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105" />
        <Button Content="Save" Margin="0,0,12,23" Name="btnSave" Click="btnSave_Click" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="71" />
        <Button Content="Close" Margin="0,0,89,23" Name="btnClose" Click="btnClose_Click" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="61" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="338,36,0,0" Name="txtRef" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="46" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <Label Content="ID Ref" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="288,36,0,0" Name="labID" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65" />
        <Button Content="..." Height="23" Margin="488,103,0,0" Name="btnBrowse" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="27" Click="btnBrowse_Click" />
        <CheckBox Content="Enabled" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,12,0,0" Name="ckenabled" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Label Content="File Name" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,132,0,0" Name="lab_filename" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,132,0,0" Name="txtSaveName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="223" />
        <TextBlock Height="17" Margin="3,0,0,1" Name="txtLastStatus" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,161,0,0" Name="txtFreqUnit" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="46" />
        <Label Content="Download Frequency" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,159,0,0" Name="labFreq" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" />
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbFreqVal" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="194,161,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="69">

        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CS:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using FileDownloadService.ClassLib;
using MessageBox = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox;

namespace FileDownloadService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for FileEditorWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class FileEditorWindow : Window
    {
        public string Mode = "none";

        public class FreqUnit
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public override string ToString() { return this.Name; }
        }


        public FileEditorWindow(string args)
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            //build up freqUnit list
            this.cmbFreqVal.Items.Add(new FreqUnit { Name = "Seconds" });
            this.cmbFreqVal.Items.Add(new FreqUnit { Name = "Minutes" });
            this.cmbFreqVal.Items.Add(new FreqUnit { Name = "Hours" });


            if (args == null)
            {
                //do nothing

                Mode = "add";

                //populate default save location
                XmlInterface getConfig = XmlInterface.DeserializeConfiguration(Globals.ConfigFileName);
                txtSaveLoc.Text = getConfig.defaultSaveLoc;


            }
            else
            {
                Mode = "edit";

                //New instance of the editor class
                Editor oEditor = new Editor();

                //launch method to obtain selected record data
                string[] SelectedRecordData = oEditor.ReadRecord(args);

                //is the item enabled or disabled
                bool enabledResult;
                if (SelectedRecordData[4] == "1")
                {
                    enabledResult = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    enabledResult = false;
                }

                //populate form
                txtRef.Text = SelectedRecordData[0];
                txtDownloadName.Text = SelectedRecordData[1];
                txtURL.Text = SelectedRecordData[2];
                txtSaveLoc.Text = SelectedRecordData[3];
                ckenabled.IsChecked = enabledResult;
                txtSaveName.Text = SelectedRecordData[5];
                txtLastStatus.Text = SelectedRecordData[6];
                txtFreqUnit.Text = SelectedRecordData[7];
                cmbFreqVal.Text = SelectedRecordData[8];



            }


        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var mainForm = new MainWindow();

            Close();


        }


        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Mode == "add")
            {
                Editor rEditor = new Editor();


                if (rEditor.WriteRecord(Mode, ckenabled.IsChecked, txtDownloadName.Text, txtRef.Text, txtURL.Text, txtSaveLoc.Text, txtSaveName.Text, txtFreqUnit.Text, cmbFreqVal.SelectedItem.ToString()) == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Item Added Successfully");
                }



            }
            if (Mode == "edit")
            {

                Editor rEditor = new Editor();



                if (rEditor.WriteRecord(Mode, ckenabled.IsChecked, txtDownloadName.Text, txtRef.Text, txtURL.Text, txtSaveLoc.Text, txtSaveName.Text, txtFreqUnit.Text, cmbFreqVal.SelectedItem.ToString()) == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Item Saved Successfully");
                }

            }


        }

        private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var browseDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();


            browseDialog.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;

            if (browseDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                txtSaveLoc.Text = browseDialog.SelectedPath;
            }

        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a local copy of a window in a close event?

Comment: Try to debug the application and see what threads are running after you closed the window. If there is a thread that not a background thread running, the application won't exit.

Comment: Erik, you just solved my problem. If you make it the solution I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as per my original comment, I would suggest removing the creation of a window from the close event.  :)

Answer (score 3):

```
    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mainForm = new MainWindow();  // why ???

        Close();
    }
```

In your CloseButton click you are closing the current Form but you are also creating a new one...

Remove that line and your App probably will Close. And using the [x] button should work too.